# Inflating WebView weird separation

Tags: java, android, webview

I have this weird result after doing a sample app using Cardview, Webview and fragments.

[image: Screencapture]

There is a huge gap between the CardView and the WebView.
This is my layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:showDividers="beginning"
    android:weightSum="3.0">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewLarge"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webviewLarge"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This my WebViewFragment onCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);
    String url = getArguments().getString("Link");
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webviewLarge);
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);

    return view;
}
```

and this the part where I inflate the WebView in the CardViewAdapter inside the onBindViewHolder onClick() function:

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
WebViewFragment webFragment = new WebViewFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Link", currentItem.getLink());
webFragment.setArguments(bundle);
activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
         .beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.webviewLarge, webFragment)
         .commit();

// Execute transactions now                           
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

I really don't know where I'm doing something wrong, everything works great except for that separation at the beginning of the WebView that does nothing, not even scrolls, while the Cardview and Webview do scroll.

Comment: does this occur when you go to simple non responsive (not responsive or mobile)?  I'm wondering it is the BBC site that is causing this.

Comment: In mobile I use activities and it works fine, it only occurs when I try to do it for tablets and using a Fragment.

Comment: It happens exactly the same if I load google.com as Url for the WebView.

Comment: Try turning on layout bounds [**Settings** > **Developer Options** > **Show layout bounds**]. Is the `WebView` actually shifted over? Or is the content within the `WebView` shifted?

Comment: does this occur if you omit the `android:divider` attribute? don't forget to edit the question code to include the android:weightSum attribute :)

Comment: It shows a divider at the beginning of the WebView and then another one when the content begins, so my guess is that when I inflate the WebView, it only inflates a portion of the layout, not all of it. It's really odd.

Comment: Yes it does, it occurs the same with or without dividers.